# Post to Wordpress Blog From 3rd Party App?

Tags: php, android, ios, wordpress, post

I build a number of apps for various NPO and churches.  Most of them already have an announcement or news blog set up using wordpress, which I will display in their app.  This works well, but I have wondered if there is any way to set up the app to be able to allow posting to the wordpress blog from their own app, instead of having to use computer or the official wordpress app.  Is there an API or any way to do this?

Comment: this is possible. http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support

Comment: I had seen that, but not much documentation on how to use it from iOS.  I had found https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPressApi but it seems to be missing a bunch of stuff, as even the example won't build without errors.